# Trouble Training Same Tensorflow Model in PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have trained a model in Tensorflow and am having trouble replicating it in PyTorch. The Tensorflow model achieves near 100% accuracy (the task is simple), but the PyTorch model performs at random. I've spent a while trying to figure this out, and can't understand what the problem could be.

The model is trained for the task of binary classification. Given an input utterance describing a quadrant and a `(x, y, z)` coordinate, the model has to predict if the `(x, z)` portion of the coordinate is in the quadrant described. For example, if the input text was "quadrant 1" and the coordinate was `(0.5, -, 0.5)`, then the prediction should be true, but if the region was "quadrant 2" with the same coordinate, then the prediction should be false.

I generated some data and trained the model in Tensorflow using this code:

```
x_data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 1], name="x_data")
y_data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 1], name="y_data")
z_data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 1], name="z_data")
# text and labels placeholders
text_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [FLAGS.batch_size, maxtextlength])
text_lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [FLAGS.batch_size])
y_labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [FLAGS.batch_size])

# encode text and coordinate
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([100, embedding_size], -1, -1))
rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, text_data)
rnn_layers = [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size, initializer=tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.glorot_normal) for size in [256]]
multi_rnn_cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

text_outputs, text_fstate = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=multi_rnn_cell,
                                             inputs=rnn_inputs,
                                             dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=text_lengths)

# have fully connected layers to map them the input coordinates into the same dimension as the LSTM output layer from above
x_output_layer = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(x_data_placeholder, units=FLAGS.fc_column_size, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='x_coordinate')
y_output_layer = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(y_data_placeholder, units=FLAGS.fc_column_size, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='y_coordinate')
z_output_layer = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(z_data_placeholder, units=FLAGS.fc_column_size, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='z_coordinate')

# add the representations
total_output_layer = x_output_layer + y_output_layer + z_output_layer + lstm_output_layer

# make the predictions with two fully connected layers
fc_1 = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(total_output_layer, units=FLAGS.hidden_layer_size, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_1')
logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(fc_1, units=FLAGS.output_dims, activation=None, name='logits')

# train the model
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_labels_placeholder, logits=logits))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate, epsilon=1e-7)
gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, FLAGS.gradient_clip_threshold)
optimize = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

# then it'll be trained with sess.run ...
```

Now for the PyTorch replication:

```
class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()

        self.encode_x = nn.Linear(1, embed_size)
        self.encode_y = nn.Linear(1, embed_size)
        self.encode_z = nn.Linear(1, embed_size)
        self._embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, self.embedding_table_size)
        nn.init.uniform_(self._embeddings.weight, -1.0, 1.0)
        self.num_layers = 1
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(self.embedding_table_size, self.hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.fc_after_text_lstm = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 100)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(100, 256) 
        self.fc_final = nn.Linear(256, 2) 
        self.relu_activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size, device='cuda:0'):
        # for LSTM, we need # of layers
        h_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        return h_0, c_0

    def forward(self, input_text, x_coordinate=None, y_coordinate=None, z_coordinate=None):
        x_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_x(x_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32)).cuda())
        y_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_y(y_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32))).cuda()
        z_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_z(z_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32))).cuda()

        embeds = self._embeddings(input_text)
        embedding, hidden = self.rnn(embeds, self.hidden)
        text_fc = self.relu_activation(self.fc_after_text_lstm(embedding[:, -1]))
        representations_so_far_added = torch.sum(torch.stack([text_fc, x_embed, y_embed, z_embed]), dim=0)
        pre_final_embedding = self.relu_activation(self.fc(representations_so_far_added))
        
        return self.fc_final(pre_final_embedding )

### training code
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, eps=1e-7)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
for input_text, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, z_coordinate, targets, train_data:

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    pred = model(input_text, x_coordinate=x_coordinate, y_coordinate=y_coordinate, z_coordinate=z_coordinate)
    loss = criterion(pred.float(), targets)
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 5.0)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()

    # accuracy evaluation code, this is evaluated over the entire epoch
    pred_idx = F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1)
    target_labels = targets.cpu().int()
    pred_labels = torch.argmax(pred_idx, dim=-1).cpu().data.int()
    curr_acc = skm.accuracy_score(target_labels, pred_labels)
```

If anyone can spot any issue with the PyTorch implementation or maybe tell me what could be wrong, that would be much appreciated! I also tried to load the weights of the Tensorflow model into all the appropriate layers, and performance still struggles in PyTorch! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I have created a minimally reproducible example, because I still cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be still appreciated!

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

lr = 0.0005
n_epochs = 10
input_dim = 4    
hidden_dim = 128
layer_dim = 2
output_dim = 2
batch_size = 50

class FeatureDataSet(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train, x_coordinates):
        self.x_train = torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.long)
        self.y_train = torch.tensor(y_train)
        self.x_coordinates = torch.tensor(x_coordinates, dtype=torch.float32)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y_train)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x_train[idx], self.y_train[idx], self.x_coordinates[idx]


class RNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.layer_dim = layer_dim

        # linear layer to encode the coordinate
        self.encode_x = nn.Linear(1, hidden_dim).cuda()
        self._embeddings = nn.Embedding(40, 100).cuda()

        # hidden_dim is 128
        # layer_dim is 2
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(100, hidden_dim, layer_dim, batch_first=True).cuda()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(2 * hidden_dim, output_dim).cuda()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.hidden = None

    def init_hidden(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim)
        return [t.cpu() for t in (h0, c0)]

    def forward(self, x, x_coordinate):
        #initializing the hidden states
        h0, c0 = self.init_hidden(x)
        embeds = self._embeddings(x)
        out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(embeds.cuda(), (h0.cuda(), c0.cuda()))

        x_embed = F.relu(self.encode_x(x_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32)).cuda())
        representations_so_far_added = torch.cat([out[:, -1, :], x_embed], dim=1)

        out = self.fc(representations_so_far_added)
        return out

    

model = RNN(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim, batch_size)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

print('Start model training')
import sklearn.metrics as skm
import torch.nn.functional as F


x_train = []
x_coordinates = []
y_train = []
for i in range(10000):
    # create the data. if x_coordinate > 0 and the sentence says that (represented by [1, 5, 6, 8]), then we should predict positive else negative (if the x_coordinate > 0)
    # same applies if the x_coordinate < 0, just that the sentence is now [1, 5, 6, 9]
    if np.random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
        if np.random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            # x coordinate > 0
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 8])
            x_coordinates.append([round(np.random.uniform(0.01, 1.00, 1)[0], 2)])
            y_train.append(1.0)
        else:
            # x coordinate > 0 negative
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 8])
            x_coordinates.append([round(np.random.uniform(-1.00, 0.00, 1)[0], 2)])
            y_train.append(0.0)
    else:
        if np.random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            # x coordinate < 0
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 9])
            x_coordinates.append([round(np.random.uniform(-1.00, 0.00, 1)[0], 2)])
            y_train.append(1.0)
        else:
            # x coordinate < 0 negative
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 9])
            x_coordinates.append([round(np.random.uniform(0.01, 1.00, 1)[0], 2)])
            y_train.append(0.0)

# print a sample of data 
print(x_train[:10])
print(y_train[:10])
print(x_coordinates[:10])

# create a dataloader
trainingDataset = FeatureDataSet(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train, x_coordinates=x_coordinates)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=trainingDataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


# for each epoch
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
    acc_all = []
    # each batch
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch, x_coord_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)

        x_coord_batch = x_coord_batch.to(device)

        opt.zero_grad()
        # pass in the text (x_batch) and coordinate (x_coord_batch)
        out = model(x_batch, x_coordinate=x_coord_batch)
        loss = criterion(out.float(), y_batch.type(torch.LongTensor).cuda())
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()

        pred_idx = F.log_softmax(out, dim=1)
        target_labels = y_batch.cpu().int()
        pred_labels = torch.argmax(pred_idx, dim=-1).cpu().data.int()

        curr_acc = skm.accuracy_score(target_labels, pred_labels)
        acc_all.append(curr_acc)

    print(np.mean(acc_all))
```

Comment: I looked through your code, but couldn't come up with anything obvious. This is a bit broad of a question to ask without having everything running locally for debugging. I would start with a NN debugging guide like this: https://towardsdatascience.com/checklist-for-debugging-neural-networks-d8b2a9434f21, then I suggest posting more specific followups when you see something in that process that you can't explain well.

Comment: @DavidParks thank you for trying to help. I've looked at those things and tons more, and still can't figure out what the issue is. I posted a minimally reproducible example, that tries to solve a simpler task: Given an input sentence that says the coordinate > 0, is it?  Same for the coordinate being < 0. Thanks!

Comment: Have you used the same hyperparameters in both experiments (TensorFlow and PyTorch)?

Comment: @Ivan yes! All the training setups are the same

Comment: @hockeybro Does your "minimally reproducible example" work in TensorFlow? I think the problem with this example is reasonable, the `out[i, -1, :]` only have two possible ouput, and so does `x_embed`. You want to produce output according to their combination with a single `self.fc`, which is similar to fit a `xor` problem with a single layer of perceptron, just like [this link](https://medium.com/@lucaspereira0612/solving-xor-with-a-single-perceptron-34539f395182). I replaced the `self.fc` with two fc layers and activation function, and got accuracy near 100%.

Comment: @ I also tried your `BaselineModel`, it works fine on your dataset provided in the "minimally reproducible example", producing results with accuracy near 100%. Perhaps you should provide another example for reproducting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose perhaps there are some mistakes in **your dataset implementation** in the PyTorch version.

I tried your pytorch `BaselineModel` on both the dataset in your "minimally reproducible example" and my own dataset constructed according to your description, and find that it works fine.

The following is my codes for testing on my own dataset. Note that I add several hyperparameters to the code of `BaselineModel` to make it run. I got accuracy over 99%.

```
import random

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

lr = 0.0005
n_epochs = 100
input_dim = 4
hidden_dim = 128
layer_dim = 2
output_dim = 2
batch_size = 50


class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count


class FeatureDataSet(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train, x_coordinates, y_coordinates, z_coordinates):
        self.x_train = torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.long)
        self.y_train = torch.tensor(y_train)
        self.x_coordinates = torch.tensor(x_coordinates, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y_coordinates = torch.tensor(y_coordinates, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.z_coordinates = torch.tensor(z_coordinates, dtype=torch.float32)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y_train)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x_train[idx], self.y_train[idx], self.x_coordinates[idx], self.y_coordinates[idx], self.z_coordinates[idx]


class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()
        vocab_size = 40
        self.hidden_size = 100
        self.embedding_table_size = self.hidden_size
        self.encode_x = nn.Linear(1, self.hidden_size)
        self.encode_y = nn.Linear(1, self.hidden_size)
        self.encode_z = nn.Linear(1, self.hidden_size)
        self._embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, self.embedding_table_size)
        nn.init.uniform_(self._embeddings.weight, -1.0, 1.0)
        self.num_layers = 1
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(self.embedding_table_size, self.hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.fc_after_text_lstm = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 100)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(100, 256)
        self.fc_final = nn.Linear(256, 2)
        self.relu_activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

        self.hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size, device='cuda:0'):
        # for LSTM, we need # of layers
        h_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        return h_0, c_0

    def forward(self, input_text, x_coordinate=None, y_coordinate=None, z_coordinate=None):
        x_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_x(x_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32)).cuda())
        y_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_y(y_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32))).cuda()
        z_embed = self.relu_activation(self.encode_z(z_coordinate.cuda().to(torch.float32))).cuda()

        embeds = self._embeddings(input_text)
        embedding, hidden = self.rnn(embeds, self.hidden)
        text_fc = self.relu_activation(self.fc_after_text_lstm(embedding[:, -1]))
        representations_so_far_added = torch.sum(torch.stack([text_fc, x_embed, y_embed, z_embed]), dim=0)
        pre_final_embedding = self.relu_activation(self.fc(representations_so_far_added))

        return self.fc_final(pre_final_embedding)


# model = RNN(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim, batch_size)
model = BaselineModel().cuda()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

print('Start model training')
import sklearn.metrics as skm
import torch.nn.functional as F

x_train = []
x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []
z_coordinates = []
y_train = []
for i in range(10000):
    x_coordinate = round(np.random.uniform(-1, 1.00, 1)[0], 2)
    y_coordinate = round(np.random.uniform(-1, 1.00, 1)[0], 2)
    z_coordinate = round(np.random.uniform(-1, 1.00, 1)[0], 2)
    x_coordinates.append([x_coordinate])
    y_coordinates.append([y_coordinate])
    z_coordinates.append([z_coordinate])

    if np.random.randint(0, 2) == 0: # positive example
        if x_coordinate <= 0 and z_coordinate <= 0:
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 8])
        elif x_coordinate <= 0 and z_coordinate > 0:
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 9])
        elif x_coordinate > 0 and z_coordinate <= 0:
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 10])
        elif x_coordinate > 0 and z_coordinate > 0:
            x_train.append([1, 5, 6, 11])
        y_train.append(1.0)
    else:
        if x_coordinate <= 0 and z_coordinate <= 0:
            x_train.append(random.choice([[1, 5, 6, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [1, 5, 6, 11]]))
        elif x_coordinate <= 0 and z_coordinate > 0:
            x_train.append(random.choice([[1, 5, 6, 8], [1, 5, 6, 10], [1, 5, 6, 11]]))
        elif x_coordinate > 0 and z_coordinate <= 0:
            x_train.append(random.choice([[1, 5, 6, 8], [1, 5, 6, 9], [1, 5, 6, 11]]))
        elif x_coordinate > 0 and z_coordinate > 0:
            x_train.append(random.choice([[1, 5, 6, 8], [1, 5, 6, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10]]))
        y_train.append(0.0)



# print a sample of data
print(x_train[:10])
print(y_train[:10])
print(x_coordinates[:10])
print(y_coordinates[:10])
print(z_coordinates[:10])

# create a dataloader
trainingDataset = FeatureDataSet(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train, x_coordinates=x_coordinates, y_coordinates=y_coordinates, z_coordinates=z_coordinates)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=trainingDataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# for each epoch
loss_meter = AverageMeter()
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
    acc_all = []
    # each batch
    loss_meter.reset()
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch, x_coord_batch, y_coord_batch, z_coord_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)

        x_coord_batch = x_coord_batch.to(device)
        y_coord_batch = y_coord_batch.to(device)
        z_coord_batch = z_coord_batch.to(device)

        opt.zero_grad()
        # pass in the text (x_batch) and coordinate (x_coord_batch)
        out = model(x_batch, x_coordinate=x_coord_batch, y_coordinate=y_coord_batch, z_coordinate=z_coord_batch)
        loss = criterion(out.float(), y_batch.type(torch.LongTensor).cuda())


        loss.backward()
        opt.step()

        pred_idx = F.log_softmax(out, dim=1)
        target_labels = y_batch.cpu().int()
        pred_labels = torch.argmax(pred_idx, dim=-1).cpu().data.int()

        curr_acc = skm.accuracy_score(target_labels, pred_labels)
        acc_all.append(curr_acc)

        loss_meter.update(loss.item())

    print(np.mean(acc_all))
    print("loss is %f" % loss_meter.val)
```

---

As for the "minimally reproducible example", I think the model `RNN` doesn't work is quite reasonable, as I have stated in the comments. I suppose that tensorflow can not fit as well, although I have not tried it. Your "minimally reproducible example" may be unrelated to your main problem.

Comment: Hi, your fix solved the issue for the minimally reproducible example (that was my mistake, sorry about that), but not for the real example. I noticed that for the real code, I was able to fix the issue when my input text was shorter and not 0 padded. For example, an input tokenized text of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is working great, but if I change it to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, ...., 0]` where there are say 40 0's, then the model can't learn anything again. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @hockeybro Can model manage to handle input with this kind of padding when implemented by Tensorflow? I also failed to train when I added 40 zero paddings. The performance decrease to 75% when add 20 zero paddings. Your embedding of  `[1, 5, 6, 8, 0, ..., 0]` will be very  close to it of `[1, 5, 6, 9, 0, ..., 0]`, so perhaps a very low learning rate is needed to distinguish this two very similar embedding (Consider 2-class classification for two very close data point, of course low lr is needed). I tried set lr to `1e-5` and the accuray increase to over 80% for 20 padding.

Comment: Yeah in Tensorflow it works, I wonder why it doesn't work in PyTorch? This is very weird!

Comment: @hockeybro It's really strange and I'm sorry that I have no more idea? How do you set the learning rate for tensorflow? I also find that you use `init_hidden` to initial the hidden state to be zeros in Pytorch, how about TF? And is the clip_gradient crutial for tensorflow inplementation? I suggest you posting a new question with reproducible example of Tf and Pytorch, removing the perhaps unrelated "clip_gradient", add the implementation of two dataset and setting of hyperparameters, renaming corresponding variable in two implementation to the same name.

Comment: @hockeybro I increase the dataset size to 1e6, set batch size to 50,000, lr to 1e-5, padding 20, I get accuracy over 96%. (I interrupted training after accuracy reached 0.96, however, I believe it can continue to increase). Note that at the beginning of traning, the loss does not decrease, but suddenly drops while accuracy increases from 55% to 57%, 66%, 71% in three epochs.